# Min/Max of Vec<f64> / trait `Ord` is not implemented for xy

Tags: rust

Based on [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69665429/5011027) (which leads to [std::cmp functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/index.html#functions)), here is the working [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12df279416d5361bf9317eb0db634297)

**Problem:**
I try to get min / max of a Vec .
As f64 has NAN and Infinity, it doesn't fulfill Ord and complains about:

```
the trait `Ord` is not implemented for `f64`
```

How can I get the min/max anyhow for scenarios where NAN / Inf is never contained in the Vec?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that not all comparisons are defined - `f64` is only partially ordered. Thus, it only implements `PartialOrd`, not `Ord` though. You can however provide a comparison function that just asserts that every two values are comparable. To use your custom comparison function, you would use `min_by` instead:

```rust
let values = vec![1.0, 0.5, 42.0];
let _ = values.into_iter().min_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap());
```

Keep in mind that using `unwrap` will panic if `a` and `b` are not comparable.

Comment: I think it would be helpful for people to know that f64::min(a, b) is a function available in rust.